# How to associate these models(user, company), where User can be Employer and Employee?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

In Ruby on Rails 4, I've these models:

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company, dependent: :destroy
end

def Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So now, I want User as Employer to be able to have a company, and this Company can have many Users(Employees).

And when I log a User as Employee, I want to able to list all the companies he works.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you actually have an Employee model?

Comment: No @kurenn. Actually Employee isn't a model. But User model can behave like an employer or employee. By the way, I'm reading your APIsOnRails book, and I owe you a beer.

Comment: probably a good approach would be to add roles for your user and company with a has_many relation where the middle table is the actual role. Makes sense? I would like the beer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I could give you a full working code file without some more information, but I think this is the best way to proceed.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "users"
  #Define shared associations/methods
end

class Employee < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
  #Employee only associations/methods
end

class Employer < User
  has_one :company
  #Employer only associations/methods
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
  belongs_to :employer
end
```

Since both inherit from the same User model, they will share a table.  Since both derived models only use has_x, the foreign key will be in the other table, meaning they can share a table schema without a ton of null values.

Again I'm not sure this will work by itself, but I think it's a good start. Another advantage is that by segregating the code like this, you can independently change functions by the type of person (e.g. you could have a generic log function on user, but make it more specific on Employee and Employer - such as including the company or companies they are tied to).

---

I realized after the fact that there is another way of doing this. You can make User have a polymorphic association to either Employee or Employer.  Then you would check the user record for which type it is, then pull the association and call the methods on that record (Employee or Employer).

The only thing I don't like about this solution is that it involves 3 tables and from what I've seen you can get by with 1.